# Write a method FindPoorer() C#

Tags: c#, for-loop, methods

Can someone explain what to do with this code? i have already write FindFisrtitem() but with FindPoorer() I have a problem...

1.I need to write a method FindPoorer();. Method have to find a lowest account balance and if will not find, method need to return "Basia".

2. Same question but method need to return null.

**I don't expect 100% solution of tasks, but rather a hint**

```
using System;
namespace Poorer
{
   class Item
   {
       public Item PreviousItem { get; set; }

       public string Name { get; set; }

       public double AccountBalance { get; set; }

       public Item(string name, double balance, Item prevItem)
       {
           Name = name;
           AccountBalance = balance;
           PreviousItem = prevItem;
       }

       internal Item AddItem(string v1, int v2)
       {
           return new Item(v1, v2, this);
       }

       internal Item FindFirstItem()
       {
           //if (PreviousItem == null)
           //{
           //    return this;
           //}
           //return PreviousItem.FindFirstItem();

           var curr = this;

           while (true)
           {
               if (curr.PreviousItem == null)
               {
                   return curr;
               }
               curr = curr.PreviousItem;
           }
       }

       internal Item FindPoorer()
       {


          if(AccountBalance > 0)
           {
               return ;  
           }
           return FindPoorer(); 
       }
   }

   class ListExcercise
   {
       static void Main(string[] args)
       {
           var basia = new Item("Basia", 100, null);
           var kasia = basia.AddItem("Kasia", 50);
           var isia = kasia.AddItem("Isia", 40);
           var isia2 = isia.AddItem("Isia2", 20);
           var isia3 = isia2.AddItem("Isia3", 40);

           var first = isia3.FindFirstItem();
            var poorer = isia3.FindPoorer();


           Console.WriteLine("The poorer person is: " + poorer.Name);
       }



   }
}
```

Comment: The first element will always, **temporarily**, be the poorer. Then, any item lower than the current poorer will become the poorer.

Comment: You might also want to rename the parameters of `AddItem` to be more descriptive like `name` and `balance` instead of `v1` and `v2` describe nothing.

Comment: You can introduce a static class variable (not the best idea), or you could loop through the list like you did with `FindFirstItem`, store the poorest item in a temporary variable, and return it at the end of loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just loop through the list like you did with `FindFirstItem()`. 
Compare the current item with the poorest item (as of now) then return it when you reach the end of list.

You do not need to use recursive here.

Pseudocode:

```
internal Item FindPoorer()
{
    var curr = this;
    var poorest = this;
    while (true)
    {
        if (curr.balance < poorest.balance)
        {
            poorest = curr;
        }
        if (curr.PreviousItem == null)
        {
            return poorest;
        }
        curr = curr.PreviousItem;
    }
}
```